# Vue js : get the inputed string and display , get also lenght of string

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I would like to get the string input and display it , also number of charactrs of the string.

Need help to realize.

```
    <section id="app">
      <h2>Learn  Vue Works</h2>
      <input type="text" @input="saveInput">
      <button @click="setText">Set Text</button>
    <br>

   <p>{{ qry }} {{ message }}</p>
```

=====app.js=============================

```
const app = Vue.createApp({
  data() {
    return {
      message: 'Vue is great!',
      qry: 'Query String : ',
      currentSearchInput: '',
    };
  },
  methods: {
    setText() {
      this.message = this.currentUserInput;
    },
   saveInput(event) {
      this.currentUserInput = event.target.value;
   },
  },
});

app.mount('#app');
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Bind your `currentSearchInput` to the input using v-model. You do not need `saveInput` at all.

```html
<input v-model='currentUserInput' type="text" />
{{currentSearchInput}} {{currentSearchInput.length}}
```

```js
setText() {
      this.message = this.currentSearchInput;
    },
```

Your code has `currentSearchInput` and `currentUserInput`.  Typo?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I agree with Steven. Don't need to use `saveInput` function. Just use v-model="currentUserInput" and then when clicking the button, just set like that;

```
    setText() {
      this.message = this.currentUserInput;
    },
```